# maven-jaxb2-plugin: How to use my own EqualsStrategy

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin, jaxb2-basics

I'm using [maven-jaxb2-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin) to generate the `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

I have implemented own strategies, derived from `JAXBEqualsStrategy` and `JAXBHashCodeStrategy`.

Is there a way to tell the plugin to use those strategies instead of the default ones?

E.g. via a configuration like

```
<arg>-Xequals=my.own.EqualsStrategy</arg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost correct:

```
<build>
    <defaultGoal>test</defaultGoal>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <args>
                    <arg>-XtoString</arg>
                    <arg>-Xequals</arg>
                    <arg>-Xequals-equalsStrategyClass=my.own.EqualsStrategy</arg>
                    <arg>-XhashCode</arg>
                    <arg>-XhashCode-hashCodeStrategyClass=my.own.HashCodeStrategy</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

If your strategies are stateless (they should normally be), you can create singleton instances as public static final `INSTANCE` fields in strategy classes. You can then include the JAR with your strategies as `configuration/plugins/plugin` (just to add it to the XJC classpath) and generated code will use the `INSTANCE` fields instead of creating new instances of strategies.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of [JAXB2 Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics), JAXB plugin package in question.

Comment: That's a straight forward solution. I wish I had found this in the documentation. So, while tinkering, I ended up using the maven-replacer-plugin to find and replace all occurences of of JaxBEqualsStragegy with my.own.EqualsStrategy from the generated code.